# Quiz program in Java

Tags: java, array, swing

I have made this small quiz with 10 question and 40 `JRadioButton`s. One question and 4 `JRadionButton`s for each panel. So I had to create an array of `JRadioButton`s and `JPanel`s, and for all I need to call `setText`.

Can this project be done with only four `JRadioButton`s, so when someone clicks on next question, the radio buttons will be removed from that panel and added to next?

```
package Quiz;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Quiz {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel p1,p2,p3;
private JLabel [] arrayLabels;
private JRadioButton [] arrayRButtons;
private ButtonGroup[] arrayGroups;
private JPanel [] arrayPanels;
private CardLayout cl;
private JLabel lb1,lb2;
private JButton btn1,btn2;
private Timer tim;
private int t,s;

public Kviz(){
prepareGUI();
}

private void prepareGUI(){

frame=new JFrame();
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

p1=new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

lb1=new JLabel("Wellcome to quiz");

cl=new CardLayout();

p2=new JPanel();
p2.setLayout(cl);

arrayPanels = new JPanel[10];

//A series of panels on which will rotate and show questions and answers
for(int i=0;i<arrayPanels.length;i++){

    arrayPanels[i] = new JPanel();
    p2.add(arrayPanels[i], String.valueOf(i));
    arrayPanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

}

//Array RadioButtons with text

arrayRButtons = new JRadioButton[40];

for(int i=0;i<arrayRButtons.length;i++){
    arrayRButtons[i] = new JRadioButton();

    switch(i){
        case 0:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Mesopotamia");
            break;
        case 1:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Greece");
            break;
        case 2:arrayRButtons[i].setText("China");
            break;
        case 3:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Egypt");
            break;
        case 4:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Kinshasa");
            break;
        case 5:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Lagos");
            break;
        case 6:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Ulan Bator");
            break;
        case 7:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Abu Dhabi");
            break;
        case 8:arrayRButtons[i].setText("United Kingdom");
            break;
        case 9:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Norway");
            break;
        case 10:arrayRButtons[i].setText("USA");
            break;
        case 11:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Denmark");
            break;
        case 12:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Step mom");
            break;
        case 13:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Runaway Bride");
            break;
        case 14:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Grease");
            break;
        case 15:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Nothing Hill");
            break;
        case 16:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Neil Armstrong");
            break;
        case 17:arrayRButtons[i].setText("John Lenon");
            break;
        case 18:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Martin Luter King");
            break;
        case 19:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Winston Churchill");
            break;
        case 20:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Mecca");
            break;
        case 21:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Medina");
            break;
        case 22:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Dubai");
            break;
        case 23:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Riyadh");
            break;
        case 24:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Spain");
            break;
        case 25:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Venice");
            break;
        case 26:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Portugal");
            break;
        case 27:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Genoa");
            break;
        case 28:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Holocaust");
            break;
        case 29:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Perl Harbour");
            break;
        case 30:arrayRButtons[i].setText("The attack on France");
            break;
        case 31:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Blitzkrieg on Poland");
            break;
        case 32:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Bon");
            break;
        case 33:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Munich");
            break;
        case 34:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Leipzig");
            break;
        case 35:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Hamburg");
            break;
        case 36:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Chile");
            break;
        case 37:arrayRButtons[i].setText("East Timor");
            break;
        case 38:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Portugal");
            break;
        case 39:arrayRButtons[i].setText("Brazil");
            break;

    }
}

//Array button's grups 
arrayGroups=new ButtonGroup[10];

int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<arrayGroups.length;i++){

arrayGroups[i] = new ButtonGroup();

arrayGroups[i].add(arrayRButtons[j]);
arrayGroups[i].add(arrayRButtons[j+1]);
arrayGroups[i].add(arrayRButtons[j+2]);
arrayGroups[i].add(arrayRButtons[j+3]);

j+=4;
}

//Labels array with questions
arrayLabels = new JLabel[10];

for(int i=0;i<arrayLabels.length;i++){
    arrayLabels[i] = new JLabel();
    switch(i){
        case 0:arrayLabels[i].setText("The homeland of Olympics is");
            break;
        case 1:arrayLabels[i].setText("What is the capital of Nigeria");
            break;
        case 2:arrayLabels[i].setText("Which country have Greenland");
            break;
        case 3:arrayLabels[i].setText("In which the film except \"Pretty Women\" acters are Julia Roberts and Richard Gere");
            break;
        case 4:arrayLabels[i].setText("What is the first man on the moon?");
            break;
        case 5:arrayLabels[i].setText("The capital city of Saudi Arabia");
            break;
        case 6:arrayLabels[i].setText("Christopher Columbus come from ");
            break;
        case 7:arrayLabels[i].setText("Which the event stated the United States to engage in war");
            break;
        case 8:arrayLabels[i].setText("Which city was the capital in the unification of Germany");
            break;
        case 9:arrayLabels[i].setText("In which country dictator Salazar was in power ");
            break;
    }
}

p3=new JPanel();
p3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

//Rotate panels with questions
btn1=new JButton("Next question");
btn1.setEnabled(false);
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        cl.next(p2);
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        t=10;
        lb2.setText(String.valueOf(t));
        tim.start();
        btn1.setText("Next question");
    }
});


btn2=new JButton("Answer on question");
btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        tim.stop();
        btn1.setEnabled(true);

        if(arrayRButtons[1].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[5].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[11].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[13].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[16].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[23].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[27].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[29].isSelected()
            ||arrayRButtons[32].isSelected()){
            s+=10;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
        } else if(arrayRButtons[36].isSelected()){
            s+=10;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct, you won: "+s+" points");
            btn1.setText("Start again quiz");
        }else if(arrayRButtons[33].isSelected()
                ||arrayRButtons[34].isSelected()
                ||arrayRButtons[35].isSelected()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong, you won: "+s+" points");
            btn1.setText("Start again quiz");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arrayGroups[i].clearSelection();
        }
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
    }

});

t=10;

//Taimer
lb2=new JLabel("10");
tim=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(t>0){
        t--;
        lb2.setText(String.valueOf(t));
        }else{
            tim.stop();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time's up");
            btn2.setEnabled(false); 
            btn1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startGUI(){
p1.add(lb1);

p3.add(btn1);
p3.add(btn2);
p3.add(lb2);

int q=0;
for(int w=0;w<10;w++){

arrayPanels[w].add(arrayLabels[w]);
arrayPanels[w].add(arrayRButtons[q]);
arrayPanels[w].add(arrayRButtons[q+1]);
arrayPanels[w].add(arrayRButtons[q+2]);
arrayPanels[w].add(arrayRButtons[q+3]);

q+=4;
}

frame.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(p3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

cl.show(p2, "0");

tim.start();
frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Quiz start=new Quiz();
start.startGUI();

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to improve the title and grammar. I hope your don't mind :)

Comment: It would be nice if you consistently indented your code. There are several code blocks (such as the body of your `main` method) that are flat on the left margin. This is just bad, and if other people are going to read it (your teacher, your peers, or us), you should do your best to enhance readability. And even if other people won't have to read it (this is rarely the case), writing it in an easier on the eyes manner makes you brain less tired from decoding the information and you able to do more with your day. Just wrote this because you seem to be starting out and could use some advice.

Comment: the code in my project don't looks like here, i don't have a time to correct every line of code and every { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this project be done with only four JRadioButtons?

Yes.  You can do the project with only one JPanel.  The secret is to separate your GUI model from your GUI view and your GUI controllers.

I created a Java data object class to hold a question and a number of answers.

```
package com.ggl.quiz;

public class QuizQuestion {

    private final int correctAnswerIndex;

    private final String question;

    private final String[] answers;

    public QuizQuestion(String question, int correctAnswerIndex,
            String... answers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex;
    }

    public String[] getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return answers[correctAnswerIndex];
    }

}
```

Because we use a Java data object, we're not limited to 4 answers per question.

Now, we create another Java data object class to create the questions and the answers.

```
package com.ggl.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QuizQuestions {

    private List<QuizQuestion> quizQuestions;

    public QuizQuestions() {
        this.quizQuestions = addQuizQuestions();
    }

    public List<QuizQuestion> getQuizQuestions() {
        return quizQuestions;
    }

    private List<QuizQuestion> addQuizQuestions() {
        List<QuizQuestion> quizQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

        String question = "The homeland of the Olympics is?";
        String[] answers1 = { "Mesopotamia", "Greece", "China", "Egypt" };
        QuizQuestion quizQuestion = new QuizQuestion(question, 1, answers1);
        this.quizQuestions.add(quizQuestion);

        question = "What is the capital of Nigeria?";
        String[] answers2 = { "Kinshasa", "Lagos", "Ulan Bator", "Abu Dhabi" };
        quizQuestion = new QuizQuestion(question, 1, answers2);
        this.quizQuestions.add(quizQuestion);

        // Add the remainder of the questions and answers here

        return quizQuestions;
    }
}
```

You have to create one more Java data object to hold the number of questions and the number of questions answered correctly.

With these Java data objects, you can now create a GUI view with one JPanel and one set of JRadioButtons.  I'll leave this as an exercise for you, since I've already spent 45 minutes of my life creating and composing this answer.

Comment: why you use list instead of array

Comment: @GlacialMan: With a List, I don't have to specify how many questions I'm asking.

Comment: but now than you can get some question from the list if the question don't have any number(like we have in array)

Comment: @GlacialMan: List.get(0) gets the first question from the list.  Or, you can use a for (QuizQuestion qq : list) statement.

Comment: Why you have 1 in both of quizQuestion,
QuizQuestion quizQuestion = new QuizQuestion(question, **1**, answers1);
quizQuestion = new QuizQuestion(question,**1**, answers2); - why here isn't 2

Comment: @GlacialMan: The integer in the second position is an index to the correct answer.  If the correct answer to "What is the capital of Nigeria?" is "Ulan Bator", change the 1 to a 2.